# While integrate newrelic to couchbase getting "couchbase-open-source-integration (unsupported)"

Tags: couchbase, apple-m1, newrelic, apple-silicon

When I try to integrate newrelic to couchbase I'm getting `couchbase-open-source-integration  (unsupported)`.
I'm using Apple silicon M1. My couchbase is running on docker but I don't have much knowledge about newrelic. Is there another way to integrate newrelic to couchbase or how can I support newrelic in couchbase

Comment: Some more detail about what you are doing to try to integrate would be helpful. CLI commands? Code? Config files?

Comment: I'm sorry I passed that part. I'm following this document
https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/infrastructure/host-integrations/host-integrations-list/couchbase-monitoring-integration/
firstly I installed  NewRelic's infrastructure agent. Then I clicked the "Guided install" it gave me the command to run on the terminal then it returns "couchbase-open-source-integration (unsupported)"